# How to create a Node.js API that can send progress indication data to the front view?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, progress-bar

I'm working on a MEAN project as my hobby. I use Node.js as the back end and Angular.js as the front end. Node.js will execute a long lasting task (it takes about 30 minutes to execute this task), I want to display the task status on the view page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: As is this question is stated very broadly... you can use polling with a $timeout loop and $http to update the UI, if you need closer to near real time updating you could explore some socket based solutions like socket.io but as is this isn't a straightforward or easy question to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `socket.io` is a good choice.

Socket.IO enables real-time bidirectional event-based communication. And with this, Server can take the initiative to send message to Client.

Visit http://socket.io/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are talking about is a streamed request.
Take a look at this http://strongloop.com/strongblog/streaming-chunked-html-node-js-data/.

And in the front-end there is a Javascript API method called EventSource that can read a streamed response or as someone else mentioned you can use sockets if you need bi-directional communication.