# Show loading process png when use Ajax upload in Node JS

Tags: ajax, node.js

I use Ajax in Jquery npm to upload file to Server API. And I want during server is processing that file, the client side show one image loading PNG. I need help on this issue.Thanks very so much

This is my code Ajax

```
jquery.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload/contact',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (r) {
        if (r.statusCode == 0) {
          this.setState({success: 'Upload file success', error: false})
          window.location.reload();
        }
        else if (r.statusCode == -1) {
          this.setState({error: r.error, success: false})
          React.findDOMNode(this.refs.fileUpload).value = ''
        }
      }.bind(this)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTML5 progress events if you use `<input type="file">` for file uploading. Here is how the guide how to: http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/

It isn't possible to show progress with jquery.ajax - in that case you need send some progress data from your nodejs server back to client while file processing. Some info about it can be found here [How to create a Node.js API that can send progress indication data to the front view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841184/how-to-create-a-node-js-api-that-can-send-progress-indication-data-to-the-front)

And if you just need to use file upload API and progress bar - try to look on https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ Big and stable plugin for everything about uploads